# Trace WCF service from .NET Core

Tags: .net, wcf, .net-core, trace, .net-framework-version

I have created one WCF Service (.NET Framework 4.7.2) and using the ServiceReference from the client (.NET Core 2.1) to call its methods.

My problem is that Fiddler does not trace the communication between client and web service. I have read articles about how to setup the WinHttp in Fiddler but it doesn't  work. Can you suggest any other proxy application that can trace this communication with default settings?

thanks for any help

Comment: Fiddler can capture those calls. I've been using it for months with code that cals web services. There was a problem back in [2.1. Preview 2](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/29396) that was fixed on RC1. It hasn't appeared since. Even if there's an actual problem, all you need to do is specify Fiddler's address (typically `127.0.0.1:8888`) as a proxy for your application

Comment: Do you have code that actually reproduces the problem? Fiddler definitely works. Perhaps the code generated by the Connected Services tool handles proxies differently. Or it could be a configuration issue in the application itself, eg a hard-coded proxy or `none`

Comment: thanks for the help but unfortunately it didn't fix my problem. I should change the endpoint and replace local host with computer name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by replacing the localhost with the computer name

```
ServiceReferenceCalculator.CalculatorServiceClient cltcal = new CalculatorServiceClient(); 

cltcal.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress("http://ComputerName/WCFServiceFrm/CalculatorServiceWCF.svc");            

var ss = cltcal.GetInfoAsync("TCCClient");

Console.WriteLine("TCTExecAsync : " + Convert.ToString(ss.Result));
```